# How to make a folder's background more transparent in GNOME's Overview?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, activities-overview

In GNOME, is there anyway to make a (Overview) folder's background more transparent?

To be more clear, the red area in the following screenshot is where I want it to be more transparent:

[image: Application folder with default dark gray background]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [Blur my Shell](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3193/blur-my-shell/) GNOME Shell extension.

You haven't said which Ubuntu version you use, so I will suppose that you use Ubuntu 22.04 and later. In that case, follow these steps:

1. Install the Extension Manager by opening a terminal and running:

   ```
   sudo apt isntall gnome-shell-extension-manager
   ```
2. Then open Extension Manager, click on the *Browse* tab, search for "blur my shell" and click *Install*:

   [image: Browse extensions in Extension Manager]
3. After installing the extension, go to the *Installed* tab, look for *Blur my Shell*, and click the cog icon:

   [image: Installed extensions in Extension Manager]
4. After clicking the cog icon, the extension's menu will open. Click on the *Overview* tab on the bottom of the window, enable *Application folder blur* if it isn't already enabled, and select *Transparent* in the *Application folder dialogs style*, as shown in the image below:

   [image]

That's it! Your application folders should now be transparent and blurred and you will also have blurred overview. The extension offers many more settings which you can adjust to your liking.

Comment: Thanks, this extension works great for what I want.

Comment: You're welcome! :)